# Actions on Google account linking without refresh tokens or using 3rd party provider

Tags: actions-on-google

The docs for account linking for actions on google say you must provide a refresh token for implicit flow - it doesn't mention if this is required for Authorization code flows. https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2-implicit-flow

So if I had an end point that produces access tokens but doesn't issue refresh tokens (the access tokens do expire but I require a user to authenticate again in this instance - this is a security requirement outside of my control) can we still use the Authorization Code flow in this instance?

Finally how would this work with 3rd party login providers? So if I offer Facebook Login on my web app then I also won't receive a refresh token. I know I can get an extended Facebook token, but again there's no guarantee a user will use my action whilst that token is valid.

In both cases do we just return a 401 unauthorized error and will this prompt the user to sign in again from a google action side?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [the Google Assistant Smart Home sample](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actionssdk-smart-home-nodejs), which uses Authorization codes. When the HomeGraph makes an HTTP request to your cloud, it does so for a particular user. It tries to include a token, but if the token expired, it sends a new request to get the latest access token.

Comment: But does this sample also not use the refresh token? Even the docs state that a refresh token must be provided even for Auth Code flows

https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2-code-flow#token_creation

Comment: The sample does have an included OAuth implementation that works with the Assistant.

Comment: I'm not saying it doesn't include an OAuth implementation. I'm saying it also makes use of refresh tokens and my question and comment is around how I can't provide a refresh token but the docs say one is required.

Comment: I'm not really an expert on the full implementation of OAuth, so I'm not too sure what would happen in that instance.

Comment: I'm gonna knock up an oauth server quickly for a test and see what the behaviour is then report back. thanks

Comment: So I looked at this and google does indeed expect all four fields at the moment. So the OAuth server must provide a refresh token